# c# - getting the same random number repeatedly

Tags: c#, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Random number generator not working the way I had planned (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-not-working-the-way-i-had-planned-c)

Hi,

Below is the complete code for a small app I am writing - it returns an ArrayList of alphanumeric codes. The problem I have is that when 'stepping' through the code the e.Result is returned correctly with each item being different. However, if I let the app run without the breakpoints I just get multiple instances of the same variable back:

```
    public partial class AlphaNum : Form
{
    public AlphaNum()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Initialise BackGroundWorker Reporting
        backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

        // Initialise BackGroundWorker Cancel
        backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        button1.Enabled = false;
    }


    private int RandomNumber(int min, int max)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.Next(min, max);
    }

    public string RandomString(Random r, int len)
    {
        string str = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((len--) > 0)
            sb.Append(str[(int)(r.NextDouble() * str.Length)]);
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    private string generateCode()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int length = int.Parse(stringLength.Text);
        string code = "";
        code = RandomString(rnd, length);
        return code;
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        int quantity = int.Parse(quantityRequired.Text);
        ArrayList codes = new ArrayList();
        string myText = "";

        for (int a = 0; a < quantity; a++)
        {

            myText = generateCode();
            codes.Add(myText);
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(((100 / quantity) * a));

        }

        e.Result = codes;
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage; //update progress bar
        //Console.WriteLine(time);
        //in this example, we log that optional additional info to textbox
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = true;
        ArrayList codes = new ArrayList();
        codes = (ArrayList)e.Result;

        for (int i = 0; i < codes.Count; i++  )
        {
            outputText.Text += codes[i].ToString();
            outputText.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
        }

    }


}
```

}

Can anyone explain why the result is okay when I effectively slow the process down by stepping my way through but incorrect when it runs without being stopped/slowed down?

Many Thanks

Comment: `(100 / quantity) * a` is not going to give good results, since quantity is an integer.  Try `100 * a / quantity` instead.

Comment: Agh, good ol' new Random() :) duplicate...

Comment: Everyone's alive tonight! 2 comments and 3 Answers in less than 6 mins - I'm impressed!

Answer (score 3):

The loop in `backgroundWorker1_DoWork` is so fast that the `Random` object generated in `generateCode` is always seeded with the same value, thus producing the same values. Don't recreate the `Random` object but assign one to an instance variable in the constructor of your class and only use that one.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't create a new `Random` object every time you need a random number.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
```

uses the current time to initialize the LFSR, when the program runs at full speed, the same "current time" gets used many times in a row.

Comment: Okay, so how can I get a new random number on each iteration?

Comment: Like Femaref said, create just one `Random` object and save it somewhere you can reuse it.